# Passing data through navigation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to pass a mobile number as well as a string data to check that whether the flow is from register or it is from login. So how can I do that? please provide me some help!

**register.dart**

```
class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {
  String execute_from = 'Register';
UserData _data = UserData();
   submit() async {
    if (this._formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
   print(_data.mobileNo);
 // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/otp', arguments: '${_data.mobileNo}'); /* here I want to pass 
    execute_from */
  }
}
```

**route.dart**

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SplashScreenPage());
      case '/register':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => RegisterPage());
      case '/login':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage());
      case '/otp':
        var mobNumber = settings.arguments as String;   /* Is this right way to pass? */
        var execute_from = settings.arguments as String;
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OtpPage(mobNumber, execute_from));
      case '/home':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage());
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                      child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}')),
                ));
    }
  }
}
```

**otp.dart**

```
class OtpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String mobNumber;
  final String execute_from;
  String formattedMobNo;

  OtpPage(this.mobNumber, this.execute_from) {
    formattedMobNo = this.mobNumber.replaceRange(2, 8, 'XXXXXX');
    print(execute_from);

  }
 //........
}
```

Please tell me how can I receive those on my otp page.

Comment: what you are getting in `print(execute_from);`

Comment: Nothing! only I am receiving the mobile number @Shubham Narkhede

Comment: How you are passing `mobNumber` to `OtpPage`

Comment: Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/otp', arguments: '${_data.mobileNo}');

Comment: kindly please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to pass `arguments` as array like below,

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/otp', arguments: [
  _data.mobileNo.toString(),
  execute_from.toString()
]);
```

and then in your `RouteGenerator` class convert the receiving format to List like this

```
var mobNumber = settings.arguments as List;
```

and then simply print and check your value

```
print("==========>>mobile_number${mobNumber[0].toString()}");
print("==========>>mobile_number${mobNumber[1].toString()}");
```

and here you navigate to `OtpPage` like this

```
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OtpPage(mobNumber: mobNumber[0].toString(), execute_from: mobNumber[1].toString()));
```

And your OTP page should be like this

```
class OtpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  var mobNumber;
  var execute_from;

  OtpPage({this.mobNumber, this.execute_from});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _selectionScreen();
  }
}

class _selectionScreen extends State<OtpPage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    print("===================>>${widget.mobNumber}");
    print("===================>>${widget.execute_from}");
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

I hope this will help for you

Comment: on `RouteGenerate`  `OtpPage()` constructor requires 2 arguments.

Comment: no not needed. `settings.arguments as List` will get 2 arguments. You can check first by the print statement. Also, you can check the answer again I updated

Comment: but it is showing, 2 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. Simply I want when redirecting from login to otp page, that mobile number and that hard coded value should be printed on otp page.

Comment: `2 positional argument(s) expected` where you are getting this?

Comment: @abhipsabiswal please recheck and read carefully my answer.

Comment: Many many thanks! @Shubham Narkhede. Really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using a RouteGenerator with a Switch statement, when the Material app already does all this work for you. You can extract the arguments on the receiving class directly, as shown in the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments).

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final String mobileNo = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

...
```

Comment: No. I only want to pass that hard coded variable data to otp page.