# How to pass two arguments using Navigator.pushNamed method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to pass two arguments through the `Navigator.pushNamed` method. I tried the following but it didn't work.

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/loading', arguments:id, apikey);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array like this. For more detail please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65845439/passing-data-through-navigation-in-flutter) answer

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/loading', arguments:[id, apikey]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple arguments using the map in the .pushNamed() function like this:

`Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/loading', arguments: {'id': id, 'apikey': apikey});`

OR

`Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/loading', arguments: {'id': id, 'apikey': apikey});`

OR

You can pass an array like this:

`Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/loading', arguments: [id, apikey]);`

Answer (score 0):

Modify `onGenerateRoute` in `MaterialApp` to match like this:

```
MaterialApp(
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    if (settings.name == '/page2') {
      final data = settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => Page2(
          id: data['id'],
          apiKey: data['apiKey'],
        ),
      );
    }
    return null;
  },
)
```

This is how you should be passing a `Map`.

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
  context,
  '/page2',
  arguments: {'id': your_id, 'apiKey': your_api_key},
);
```

This is your `Page2` widget:

```dart
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String apiKey;
  const Page2({Key key, this.id, this.apiKey}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container();
}
```